# Xcode 8.0 upgrade breaks Android Studio 2.1.3 NDK?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, xcode8

This makes no sense to me, after upgrading from Xcode 7.x to Xcode 8.0 on my Mac OSX 10.11.6, my Android Studio NDK build shows me the following error:

> :myapp:compileLint 
>   :myapp:copyDebugLint 
>   :myapp:ndkBuild 
>   Agreeing to Xcode/iOS license requires admin privelage, please re-run as root via sudo
>
> > Error:Execution failed for task ':myapp:ndkBuild'.
> >     Process 'command '/Users/development/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 69

Comment: Do you have git setup with Android Studio? I had the same problem when I updated Xcode. All I needed to do was open Xcode and accept the terms and conditions and Android Studio worked normally.

Comment: iRuth yep that worked for me too. What I don't understand is that I thought the Android NDK toolset had its own compilers (clang and gcc) but I think those are shared between the IDEs (Xcode & Android Studio) and when the Xcode license agreement is not clicked the permissions to those directories are changed.  That's why Android Studio is suggesting running the build with sudo...

Comment: I don't understand it either, but that's what worked.

Comment: I just filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223346. I wouldn't expect us to need anything from Xcode since, as you said, the NDK ships all its own tools...

Comment: Need more info on that bug. @neuman8, could you go fill in more info there? If we don't get the info it can't get fixed.

Comment: @Dan Albert, I added more info in the IssueTracker, let me know if more is needed...